# Unable to save file in /etc/ssh/ because incorrect permissions (Linux Mint/Debian)

Tags: linux, permissions, etc

When  I attempt to edit '/etc/ssh/sshd_config', and save the file, I get an error saying: 'Could not save the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config. You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file.. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.' How do I get the permissions I need to save the file?

Comment: Use `sudo`.  Create a new file in /tmp.  Make sure it's what you want.  Then `cat /tmp/new-file | sudo tee /etc/ssh/sshd_config` . Or just `sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config` if you like living on the edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sudo`. Create a new file in `/tmp`. Make sure it's what you want. Then `cat /tmp/new-file | sudo tee /etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Thank you 'user:4530' William Pursell for posting the answer in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

You may not a sudoer.
First switch to root user with sudo -i command and edit the files that have root owner.
Other way is to use with sudo command if your user has permission to edit this file.